# Powershell envrionment variable inheritance

Tags: powershell, inheritance, environment-variables

guys..i'm not familiar with PS and at beginning it was a simple question,but it's not so simple for me. (Sorry)

I need to take one environment variable as a string to another env. variable
something like this sketch ***"$env:$env:var"***
I've tried (of course not working,but helps to understand):

```
$env:admin1 = "123456" 

$env:user = "admin1"

$password = $env:"${env:user}"

Write-Host $password
```

Is it possible in powershell? 
Thank you!

Comment: Semantically, no, but you can grab the variable from the `env:` psdrive: `(Get-Item env:\${env:user}).Value`

Comment: I'll try and update you. Thank you. :)

Comment: Exactly what i need! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible the way you're doing it, but you can query the environment and match the variable name from a variable a number of different ways. Here's one:

```
$appData = 'APPDATA'
$value = (Get-ChildItem Env: | ? { $_.Name -eq $appData }).Value
$value # Output
```